# Insert data from XML file into existing SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server-2014, sqlxml

I need to insert data from XML file into existing SQL SERVER table. I have modified following code to INSERT INTO but its not working. I don't want to delete or create new table in this statement

```
DECLARE @x xml
SELECT @x=P
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'D:\Course Instance Marketing Data From Drupal\instance_marketing.xml', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS COURSE_INSTANCE(P)

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x


SELECT *
INTO RCMI_MARKETING_SYNC
FROM OPENXML(@hdoc,'/response/item', 2)
 WITH(
 CourseInstanceKey int '@key',
idRCMI_MARKETING_SYNC int '@key' ,
title varchar(3000),
course_code varchar(3000),
market_area varchar(3000),
ssa varchar(3000),
school_owning varchar(3000),
overview varchar(3000), 
entry_requirements varchar(3000),
teaching_methods varchar(3000),
modules_and_assessment varchar(3000),
career_options_progres varchar(3000),
equipment_needed_costs varchar(3000),
work_placement_field_trips varchar(3000)
)   

  EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

### Error

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 10
There is already an object named 'RCMI_MARKETING_SYNC' in the database.
```

I don't want to delete existing table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer

```
DECLARE @x xml
SELECT @x=P
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'D:\Course Instance Marketing Data From Drupal\instance_marketing.xml', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS COURSE_INSTANCE(P)

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

INSERT INTO RCMI_MARKETING_SYNC
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hdoc,'/response/item', 2)
WITH(
CourseInstanceKey int '@key',
idRCMI_MARKETING_SYNC int '@key' ,
title varchar(3000),
course_code varchar(3000),
market_area varchar(3000),
ssa varchar(3000),
school_owning varchar(3000),
overview varchar(3000), 
entry_requirements varchar(3000),
teaching_methods varchar(3000),
modules_and_assessment varchar(3000),
career_options_progres varchar(3000),
equipment_needed_costs varchar(3000),
work_placement_field_trips varchar(3000)
)   

  EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Comment: Glad that you found this yourself! Two hints: As stated in my answer, the approach with `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and secondly: It can be very dangerous to use `INSERT INTO TableName` without a column list. It works, and in this case it might be sufficient, but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

First of all:

Your approach with `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and remove the document is outdated. You should use [the appropriate XML methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)

If you need help with this, please start a new question with a (reduced) example of your XML and place a link here.

Your question is not related to xml actually...

Your statement with `SELECT .. INTO tbl` will create this table physically. If this table exists already, you'll get an error.

Inserts into an existing table must be written slightly differently:

```
INSERT INTO RCMI_MARKETING_SYNC(col1, col2, col3,...) --place the actual column names here
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... FROM SomeWhere           --replace this by your XML-shredding query.
```